# Local lifting property for Banach Spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, definition, banach-spaces, c-star-algebras

I am reading a paper in which the introduction of the paper talks about lifting property which I have never seen.

> Can someone explain or give me some reference for the local lifting property of Banach spaces and of $C^*$-algebra? Intuition behind the definition would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you define what lifting property you mean? The question is incomplete without this information.

Comment: I'm not aware of a second meaning for "local lifting property". Is there any? Just curious, so that I can update my answer.

Comment: @MartinArgerami I was not aware of _anything_ called a local lifting property that was appropriate to the context of functional analysis. Hence why I asked

Comment: Out of curiosity, what paper are you reading?

Answer (score 2):

A C$^*$-algebra $A$ has the *local lifting property* (LLP) if whenever you have:

- a C$^*$-algebra $B$,
- $J\subset B$ an ideal,
- $F\subset A$ a finite-dimensional operator system,
- $\phi:A\to B/J$ ucp,

there exist $\psi:A\to B$ ucp such that $\psi|_F=\phi|_F$. So $\psi$ lifts $\phi$ "locally".

The property was introduced by Kirchberg, who showed that $A$ having LLP is equivalent to the cone/suspension of $A$ having Ext a group.

It is known that the WEP implies the LLP (very non-trivial: Kirchberg showed that this is equivalent with $B(H)\odot B(H)$ admiting a single C$^*$-norm). The implication LLP $\implies$ WEP is equivalent to Connes Embedding Problem.

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you please share a reference for the same?

Comment: Kirchberg's paper is very hard to read. There are a lot of details in Ozawa's QWEP paper. Some, maybe most, of Ozawa's material is also in Brown-Ozawa.

Comment: Pro Martin Aregerami, is Connes embedding problem relevant to the sofic groups?

Comment: Yes, but I cannot say much.